# When can I take $\lim_{a \to 0}\int_a^T u$?

Tags: integration, continuity

Suppose I have a function $u:(0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is integrable over $[a,T]$ for every $a > 0$, and I have the results
$$\int_a^T u = U(T)-U(a)$$
for such $a$. When am I allowed to conclude from this that
$$\int_0^T u = U(T)-U(0)?$$

---

I think it is enough if $U$ is a continuous function on $[0,T]$. Then the RHS has a limit but is $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_a^T u = \int_0^T u$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you define $\int_0^T u$ when $u$ is not even defined at $0$?  If you define it as an improper integral, i.e. as $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_a^T u$, then 
there's no problem.  If you want it to be a Lebesgue integral, then there's 
no reason to think that $u$ will be integrable on $[0,T]$.  Try e.g.
$u(t) = \sin(1/t)/t$ (the improper integral exists and is $\pi/2 - \text{Si}(1/T)$).

Comment: oh I see. I think I need the Lebesgue integral... the thing I'm integrating is positive and continuous on (0,T], does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, if $u \ge 0$ and continuous the improper integral exists iff $u$ is integrable on $[0,T]$.